# Schema design for car table where owner could be a company or a person - should I use inheritance?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Lets say I would like to make a database of cars and their owners in Postgres. Each `car` has a unique serial code (maybe some other properties e.g. brand, color etc.) and an owner. The owner could be a `person` (name, last_name, address) or could be a `company` (registration_id, company_name)

If cars could be owned only by persons I would just add a column in the cars table with a foreign key to person_id. How would one handle it in this situation though - should I somehow use inheritance for this?